# How to scale properly after rotate the mesh without using apply rotation?

Tags: modeling, transforms, transform-orientation

i know we could use apply rotation to correct this, but here is the situation, i have mesh A and B that are joined with Ctrl + J. i just rotate the A and then want to scale along the mesh A's length without affecting Mesh B, but apply rotation(Ctrl + a) only can be used in object mode, which will affect my mesh B since they are joined.
And i saw a tutorial that do the following tricks. however, following his method i came out with some problems.

The Tutorial is in the following GIF :
https://gfycat.com/UnripeUnfortunateDanishswedishfarmdog

and following is mine:[image]

After i choose the Normal, the coordinate axes has some offset to other angel,hence scale along y axis will create some weird shape. but in the tut, the coordinate axes works perfectly. 
I strictly followed his steps but cannot find the reason.

Comment: As you don't apply rotation you can use Local orientation. That said, Normal should also work but the angle might get skewed if mesh has slight variation like some faces skewed. It seems that author of that gif gets slight deformation as well, but it's hard to tell

Comment: Thanks for replying, i tried local orientation, but it does not work as well.